# Not sure how to fit data with a gaussian python

Tags: python, curve-fitting, gaussian, data-fitting

I've tried multiple ways of fitting a gaussian to this scatterplot, but nothing has worked for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

data = loadtxt("/home/***/****/***")

t,q = data[:,2], data[:,3]                         
t,q = loadtxt("/home/***/****/***", usecols = (2,3), unpack=True)

plt.scatter(t,q, marker='.', s=20)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be a two-dimensional Gaussian?

Comment: yes, ideally a gaussian fit but any curve fit would work. It's gaussian shaped.

Comment: I use kmpfit from the kapteyn package which is writte in cython for extra speed. It works really well and there is alot of good examples here: http://www.astro.rug.nl/software/kapteyn/kmpfittutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you can just use the definitions of the mean and covariance parameters to fit them using maximum likelihood estimates from your data, right ?

```
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt("/home/***/****/***", usecols=(2, 3))
mu = data.mean(axis=0)
sigma = np.cov(data, rowvar=0)
```

In my understanding, this is what "fitting" means. However, it sounds like you're then looking to show these quantities on a plot. This can be a little trickier, but only because you need to use some linear algebra to find the eigenvectors of the estimated covariance matrix, and then use those to draw the covariance ellipse.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

# compute eigenvalues and associated eigenvectors
vals, vecs = np.linalg.eigh(sigma)

# compute "tilt" of ellipse using first eigenvector
x, y = vecs[:, 0]
theta = np.degrees(np.arctan2(y, x))

ax = plt.subplot(111)

# eigenvalues give length of ellipse along each eigenvector
w, h = 2 * np.sqrt(vals)
ax.add_artist(Ellipse(mu, w, h, theta))

# show data on top of ellipse
ax.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 1])

plt.show()
```

Comment: It says that there are too many values to unpack on the x, y = vecs[:,0] line.

Comment: Hm, not sure what to say -- works for me. Please note that when loading the data I removed the `unpack=True` keyword argument from the code you posted above. (Your covariance matrix should be of shape (2, 2).)

Comment: This worked for me as well. Just to be explicit, data should be of form: 

data= [ [x1,y1], [x2,y2], .... [xn,yn] ]

Answer (score 0):

This is coming a bit late! But the error message about too many values to to unpack can be fixed by including the option `unpack=True` when loading data i.e.

```
data = np.loadtxt("/home/***/****/***", unpack=True, usecols=(2, 3))
```